# added block returning true to equal un-tampered instance when should not block chain javascript

Tags: javascript, github, jestjs, blockchain

I am running a jest test that needs to make sure that if the data of the block matches the same data after tampering with it (which should expect false for matching.) It keeps expecting true and I am not sure why. I set the program up on a repo for people to debug. On the repo, look for blockchain.test.js and scroll to the description that says "invalidates a corrupt chain". when you npm run test the project it gets one jest error and it is that single "toBe(false)" part of the overlying function.

Github repo...

https://github.com/Mickellz/ChainAccess/commits/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant to use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but you must use backticks (`) not single quotes ('):

**block.js**

```js
static hash(timestamp,previousHash,data)
{
    return encryption('${timestamp}${lastHash}${data}').toString();
}
```

Also, `lastHash` should be `previousHash` or it will always resolve to `undefined` and won't affect the hash value.

**block.js**

```js
static hash(timestamp,previousHash,data)
{
    return encryption(`${timestamp}${previousHash}${data}`).toString();
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver! I don't know how I missed the back ticks! And the lastHash was changed when I was trying to solve this error. Thank you bro.